# VB ASP.NET WebForms app refuses to start all of a sudden

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, webforms

I don't get a 404 or any other error; the browser just spins endlessly and never connects. All I can think of is that I changed the target of a virtual directory which is inside this web app, but changing it back didn't help. What would cause a web app to behave this way? I tried it in several browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox) and they all do the same thing. At first the login page worked but no other pages worked; now I can't even access the login page.

Comment: And now it starts... Weird...  I wonder what might cause this to happen intermittently?

Comment: Seems to be triggered by adding a try/catch block around some code that is in a loop. I guess the loop executes numerous times and the try/catch block is causing the app to hang since try/catch blocks are slow?

Comment: There may be a case where it turns into an infinite loop.  Check the logic there.

Comment: Try stepping through the code.

Comment: I think you need to analyze the managed stack trace with dump file. Dump file will tell us why application hang. Then you could modify your code logic based on the analysis result. If you are not expertise in dump analysis, debug diagnostic tool  would help.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924